# c program to find the duplicate element in an ascending array using logn time complexity

Tags: c

Array is in ascending order need to find the duplicated number
Need a program with logn time complexity

```
        int n[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6};


        int size = sizeof[n];
        int mid;
            mid = size/ 2 ;
            if (a[mid] == a[mid + 1])
                        printf("%d",a[mid]);
                        return a[mid];

            else if (a[mid] != a[mid + 1])
                        for(int i=0;i<mid;i++){
                                        if(a[i]==a[mid+1])
                                           return a[i];
           }
           else
                        for(int i=mid ;mid<size;i++){
                                        if(a[mid]==a[mid+1])
                                           return a[mid];
           }
```

Comment: You need a program... Well, you seem to be on the right track. You have something written. Now, do you have a question?

Comment: 1) `int size = sizeof[n];` --> `int size = sizeof n/ sizeof *n;`

Comment: Chuck it through `clang-format` and make the code look beautiful. There's an online formatter here: [format.krzaq.cc](http://format.krzaq.cc)

Comment: i want a program in c to find the duplicate number with logn time complexity i am not aware of c ..

Comment: 2) `mid<size` --> `i < size -1`. Also Is it necessary to divide the process?

Comment: `else if (a[mid] != a[mid + 1])` has no matching `if (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the numbers must start at 0 and be increasing by 1 you can compare the middle to the index. If the middle is the same go higher, if the middle is not, go lower.

This will give you binary search time O(log2 N). The only difference is that you are comparing with the index, rather than a fixed value.
example :   int n[] = {0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6};
note: number start with 0
if number is started with 1 than change index accordingly

```
int findDuplicate(int array[],int n) {
int low = 0;
int high = n - 1;

while (low <= high) {
    int mid = (low + high)/2;
    int midVal = array[mid];

    if (midVal == mid)
        low = mid + 1;
    else
        high = mid - 1;
}
return high;
}
```